# Rails: error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, styles

Does sb. know this problem with the style-plugin?

```
 G:\testmud>rake db:migrate:down version=20130218112415
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
 for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at G:/testmud/Rakefile:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a deprecation warning to let you know that in Rails 4 storing plugins in vendor/plugins has been removed in favor of using gems.  If you have plugins in the directory, you should refactor them into ruby gems.  If the directory is empty, then you can safely delete vendor/plugins which should remove the warning message.